# Object Id on mLab MongoDB vs local MongoDB installation

Tags: mongodb

I've been using MongoDB on mLab for the past few weeks and decided to install it locally.
But the ObjectId is created differently on the local install and it's breaking my code.

Local MongoDB, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

but I don't get this error when I use mLab

On mLab the ObjectID is:

```
{
   "_id": {
       "$oid": "5ba0c426fb6fc072da03a0cf"
   },
"another field" : "another field value"
}
```

Locally it looks like:

```
_id: ObjectId("5ba6a5f080ae4c2d943deb70")
another field : another field value
```

I can't seem to jsonify my pymongo cursor db query result because of the ObjectId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this :

1. The difference between objectIds being created locally and on mLab is because MongoLab uses [Strict MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).
2. To serialise your local mongo document you can use `json_util` provided by [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html)